# In class variable cant be modified in function

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

This is the code so far:

```
class Player:
    hand = []
    def take(self, card):
        hand.append(card)
```

And this is the error when I call that function:

```
    hand.append(card)
NameError: global name 'hand' is not defined
```

I have tried making it global like so:

```
class Player:
    hand = []
    def take(self, card):
        global hand
        hand.append(card)
```

it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the variable 'hand' through the 'self' pointer:

```
class Player:
    hand = []
    def take(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
```

In Python, in a member function the self pointer always contains the value of the instance of the class that the function was called on, allowing you to edit the members of that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Quirliom said.

Unless of course you meant to have a single "hand" variable across all instances of the class (i.e. a global variable, which is what Python thinks you're trying to do, and which isn't great coding practice). In which case, you'd do:

```
hand = []

class Player:
   def take(self, card):
      hand.append(card)
```

But I'm assuming this isn't what you wanted to do, since it looks like a Poker-type scenario.